# Cannot get Parcel 2.2.1 to reliably open the dev server (npm)

Tags: parcel

I've npm installed parcel 2.2.1 as a dev dependency in a project. Very rarely, the dev server will work, but 99% of the time, running `npx parcel ./src/index.html` will cause a slight pause and then return a new terminal prompt without any output or server instance. I've tried:

- using Parcel globally instead
- serving a bare html file with no CSS or JS

It is even the case that after getting the dev server running successfully, I use Ctrl-C to close and then try to restart and it doesn't work. Computer powerdown powerup without any code change and the dev server fails still. I'm lost! Any suggestions? Node 16.13.2 x64, Windows 10

Comment: This seems to be related to Windows x64. An issue has been opened on github: https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7603

Comment: I'm having success with the depreciated v1 of parcel (`npm i parcel-bundler`) , but use at own risk... uses depreciated dependencies with vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior has now been confirmed and is an open issue on github.

https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7603

I'm using parcel 2.2.0 without issue.

```
> npm uninstall parcel
> npm i parcel@2.2.0
```